# What are invalid names for a directory under Linux?

Tags: linux

I was wondering what kinds of names are invalid for a directory under Linux, so I tried some names but I couldn't find any! Even `~` works fine! Does Linux have any restrictions for naming a directory at all?

Comment: Answered on this sister site, evidently there are only 2 characters not allowed>>>>>>https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060

Comment: Questions should show some research effort, I found the answer using google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under Linux, a directory name cannot contain:

- `/` (forward slash)
- The `NULL` character (`\0`)

Anything else is allowed, which of course can [cause lots of issues](https://dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) with shell scripts that do not properly handle whitespace (single spaces or even newlines).

Note that this applies to UNIX, the POSIX standard, and to Linux. In the [Single UNIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xbd/glossary.html), you'll find, for the definition of a filename:

> A name consisting of 1 to `{NAME_MAX}` bytes used to name a file. The characters composing the name may be selected from the set of all character values excluding the slash character and the null byte. The filenames dot and dot-dot have special meaning (…).

Comment: I tried `mkdir \0` and it makes a directory named `0`! Is bash ignoring `\` or I'm trying it in a wrong way?

Comment: It does not work this way… you'd have to run `mkdir $'\0'`. The problem is that in Bash, which is written in C, strings are terminated by a null byte. So there is no difference between doing this and `mkdir ''` — it will give you the same error.

Comment: In all Linux programs written in any language, the command-line arguments are passed as an array of C-strings which are terminated by a null byte (and have no separate length indicator). For that matter, even if you tried to use the APIs directly, the `mkdir()` kernel syscall takes C-strings as well.